# How to change text on Android Date Picker?

Tags: android, datepicker

I need the DatePicker to say "Today" instead of today's date when it spins to today. How would I do that? I have my DatePicker widget configured as follows -

```
    <DatePicker android:id="@+id/dueDatePicker"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should show you the general approach:

```
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dueDatePicker);
OnDateChangedListener listener = new OnDateChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        // Check if its the current date. isCurrentDate() is not a standard method! you have to implement it by yourself! 
        if(isCurrentDate(dayOfMonth, monthOfYear, year)) {
            // Here you can do whatever you want, if its the current date.
            view.setTitle("Today");
        }
    }
};
datePicker.init (day, month, year, listener);
```

I hope this helps a bit ;)